# Existence error on lists

Tags: prolog

I am using gprolog allong with gplc and I get `fatal error: redefining built-in predicate member/2` when I try to compile the following code. I also get `uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,member/0),member/0)` when I try to consult the same code.

Code:

```
member(X,[X|T]).
member(X,[H|T]) :- member(X,T).
```

The query I give:

```
| ?- member(X,[a,b,c,d,e]).

X = a ? ;
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,member/0),member/0)
```

Comment: Works fine in `swipl`. Are you sure there are no spacing errors in the body of the second clause? Because based on the error I would say Prolog aims to call `member/0` so without arguments.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am really new in Prolog. Can you explain me where spacing errors can exist? From my experience with the language I haven't encountered any spacing issues before. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no spacing error here. It's simple: you're trying to write a `member/2` predicate which already exists as a built-in. GNU Prolog is less forgiving about redefining built-in predicates. It will give you an error, for example, if you try to define your own `member/2` which is already a built-in. SWI Prolog is more forgiving and will let you do it. I would recommend not redefining a built-in. Any time you call the predicate, you'll be left wondering which one is being called. Why not call it, `element_of/2` or `contained_in/2`...?

Comment: @lurker But without re-implementing how to create recursion?

Comment: @lurker I have read that the facts and the rules are checked in the order that appear in the file. So this is how I know which one is evaluated each time. Can you give an example of how would you re-write this code in correct 'format'?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Just change the name of your `member` everywhere to `element_of` for example. `element_of(X,[X|T]).` and `element_of(X,[H|T]) :- element_of(X,T).` Isn't that defined recursively? And it won't give you the error. You would then call, `element_of(X, [a,b,c,d,e])`. And actually I think @WillemVanOnsem is spot on about the `member/0` error (I missed that in my first read of your question). You must have entered a space when you called it, like `member (X, [a,b,c,d,e])`, and Prolog thought you were calling `member/0` (`member` with no arguments).

Comment: @lurker Oh, man there is no other member definition in the database. Of course it didn't work! EDIT: OK, now it works, it was the space...

Comment: @lurker Actually, it doesn't work lool. Maybe it is not the spacing.

Comment: Another weird fact is that I rerunned the same code in gnu-prolog on a win machine and it worked fine :(

Comment: It's still best not to redefine a built-in. Just generally not a good idea. Also, when I tried what I suggested to you, it works perfectly fine. So you must be typing something in wrong. Or when you say "it doesn't work" are you referring to the warnings about singleton variables (which you have in your current code)? Unless you update your question to add exactly what you typed, it's hard to help you.

Comment: @lurker: what a patience !

Comment: How do you get that error **exactly**? When I do `consult(user)` I get `error: user:1: native code procedure member/2 cannot be redefined (ignored)` but you get another error?!?